# Trying to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute this integral

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right)\mathrm dx$$

Applying integration by parts

$u=\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right)$

$\mathrm du=\frac{\ln x-1}{\ln x}\left(\frac{1}{x(\ln x-1)}-\frac{\ln x}{x(\ln x-1)^2}\right)dx$

$\mathrm dv=\ln x \mathrm dx$

$v=x\ln x-x $

$$I=x(\ln x-1)\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right)-\int x(\ln x-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{x(\ln x-1)}-\frac{\ln x}{x(\ln x-1)^2}\right)\mathrm dx$$

$$I=x(\ln x-1)\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right)-\int \frac{1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx$$

this is where I got so far, but I can't continue...

Comment: Note that the indefinite integral in your last equation is non-elementary (transforming via $x\to e^t$ yields $\int \dfrac{e^t}t\ dt$), so algebraic manipulations alone won't necessarily get you there.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer as to whether that is $\ln(x-1)$ or $\ln(x)-1$?

Comment: it is $ln(x)-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last line is not quite right. It is true that

$$ \int \log x \log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log x - 1}\right) \, dx
= x(\log x - 1)\log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log x - 1}\right) + \int \frac{dx}{\log x} $$

on $(0, 1)$. But you cannot simply plug $x = 0$ or $x = 1$ since the RHS has singularity at those points. Thankfully, the lower limit $x = 0$ poses little issue, yielding

$$ \int_{0}^{a} \log x \log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log x - 1}\right) \, dx
= a(\log a - 1)\log\left(\frac{\log a}{\log a - 1}\right) + \int_{0}^{a} \frac{dx}{\log x} \tag{1} $$

For the upper limit $x = 1$, we are out of luck as the RHS becomes the difference of two divergent terms. To resolve this issue, write $a = 1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$. Our aim is to study the behavior of $\text{(1)}$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$. Now it is not hard to check that

$$ a(\log a - 1)\log\left(\frac{\log a}{\log a - 1}\right)
= -\log\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon). $$

Now using the identity $ -\log\epsilon = \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{1-x} $, we find that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \log x \log\left(\frac{\log x}{\log x - 1}\right) \, dx
&= -\log\epsilon + \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{\log x} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{\log x} \right) \, dx + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon).
\end{align*}

Now the integrand in the RHS has removable singularity at $x = 1$ and we can safely let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ to obtain

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{\log x} \right) \, dx. $$

This is a well-known representation of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.

Comment: (+1) for just playing with the asymptotical behavior.

Comment: @user23571113, Thank you. I wanted to show OP how to fix his/her computation. I also like your simple approach.

Comment: Thank you. I've always enjoyed your approaches! You're a Ramanujan of the modern times.

Answer (score 5):

Make the change of variable $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ and integrate by parts two times to arrive at

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\right)\mathrm dx=-\int_0^{\infty} \log(x) e^{-x}\mathrm dx=\gamma.$$

Comment: All to easy.  (+1) for showing a more straightforward approach.

Comment: @MarkViola thanks!